# c determining size of char buffer

Tags: c, file, size

So I am new to C and I am a bit confused about this. If I have a file and I am reading a line that is 8 bytes in length. If I am reading the line into a char buffer Should the size of temp be 8 since its 8 bytes.Because I get the line but there are some weird symbols next to it.

```
char temp[8];
fd = open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
read(fd, temp, 8); 
printf("line: %s\n",temp);
```

Comment: You should allocate an extra byte in the buffer and null-terminate the string before trying to print it.

Comment: so it should be temp[9] and make temp[9] =  '\0' ?

Comment: Yes, that should do it.

Comment: `read` will not null-terminate the string. You need to verify that the `open` call succeeded, and to check the result returned by `read`. Or you could use `fopen` and `fgets` instead.

Comment: but when I try to null terminate it I get a incompatible pointer to integer conversion warning

Comment: C has no built-in thing called a string; so do you know what a string is "made of"?

Comment: I am not quite sure

Comment: @JimLewis Thanks I got it working now

Comment: You could tell `printf()` to print only 8 bytes: `printf("%.8s\n", temp);`.  You can even use an `int` variable to specify the length: `int len = 7; printf("%.*s\n", len, temp);` to print 7 bytes.  Note, too, that newlines count as characters.  In general, you should allow for more space than just 8 bytes in a line, but using `read()` makes life trickier since it does no buffering, unlike the standard I/O functions (`fscanf()`, `fread()`, etc).

Comment: *`so it should be temp[9] and make temp[9] = '\0' ?`* No. If size is 9 then the second part should be `temp[8]='\0'`.